# Adding numbers in a list gives TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

I´m writing a simple calculator program that will let a user add a list of integers together as a kind of entry to the syntax of python. I want the program to allow the user to add as many numbers together as they want. My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Calculator.py", line 17, in <module>
    addition = sum(inputs)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

My code is:

```
#declare variables
inputs = []
done = False

#while loop for inputting numbers 
while done == False:
    value = raw_input()
#escape loop if user enters done
    if value == "Done":
        print inputs
        done = True
    else:
        inputs.append(value)

addition = sum(inputs)
print addition
```

Comment: `inputs.append(float(value))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns strings, not numbers. [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) operates only on numbers.

You can convert each item to an int as you add it to the list: `inputs.append(int(value))`. If you use `float` rather than `int` then non-integer numbers will work too. In either case, this will produce an error if the user enters something that is neither `Done` nor an integer. You can use `try`/`except` to deal with that, but that's probably out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for the detail on this answer!!

Answer (score 0):

When using `raw_input()` you're storing a string in `value`. Convert it to an int before appending it to your list, e.g.

```
inputs.append( int( value ) )
```